# reference mongodb collection from another database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have two databases named `db1` and `db2`. inside `db1` we have accounts schema like this:

```js
const accountsSchema = new Schema({
    phone: { type: String }, 
    email: { type: String },
)};
module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', accountsSchema);
```

in the same database (`db1`) we can simply reference each account like this:

```js
const engagementSchema = new Schema(
    {
        relatedAccount: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account' },
    }
);
```

**But**, what if we want to do the same thing in `db2` ? In another words I want to reference `accounts` collection which is inside `db1` **from** `db2`.

Comment: How about checking the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) before asking?

Comment: @super What a genuine kid!

Comment: @super normally I would agree, but in the case of mongoose the documentation can be a little unwieldy and hard to understand.